# get_post_pemalink() doesn't return right value

Tags: wordpress, function, permalinks

I have pretty links enabled, but when I want to retrieve url of custom post type via get_post_pemalink() I get 'not so pretty' link except pretty link.

For example:

```
function send_ad_analytics_mail($ID, $post) {
    $link       =   get_post_permalink($ID);

    $to     = 'example@gmail.com';
    $subject    = 'Post is drafted';
    $message    = 'You can see it on '  . $link;
    $headers    = array(
        'From: example@example.rs'
    );

    wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
add_action('draft_business', 'send_ad_analytics_mail', 10, 2);
```

And I get an email like this:
**You can see it on http://example.rs/?post_type=business&p=46934**
But what I want is: **You can see it on http://example.rs/business/new-jobs/**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is the hook you've chosen to use: `draft_business`.

I'm guessing that you've got a post type called "business".

And, the hook you are using as hooking into the [Post Status Transitions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions#.7Bstatus.7D_.7Bpost_type.7D_Hook) for that post.

However, because you have `draft_business`, this is hooking the status as the post is transitioned **to** the status of `draft`.  A non-published post will *never* have a pretty permalink, therefore this hook will never return a pretty permalink, but always an "ugly" one as you have shown.

Comment: Thanks @cale_b, that's perfectly make sense :)